# equally large columns in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Look at my blog's index page http://lowcoupling.com/
It is a tumblr blog based on Twitter Bootstrap
Each posts consists of a row with a col-2 column for the comments; a col-2 column for the google plus one button and a col-8 column for the post title and tags.
I can't understand why there is more space between the google plus one button and the post title than between the  comments and the plus one button.
How may I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments column is centered inside the first column, but the Google +1 button is left aligned inside the second column, giving the appearance of more space between the second and third columns. Basic spacial reasoning :)